# VBA macro to remove and/or combine duplicates and copy to a new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have an Excel file that lists product SKUs in one column and product image URLs in a another column. have over 5000 rows. My problem is that the file has multiple rows for the same product but the url of the images are different as they are different colours of the same sku. how do i combine these so each sku contains all the urls seperated via "|"

i tried to use the below code in a macro but it would not copy over the sku in the original file that only had one url, into the second sheet. what is the right macro for this.

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
 Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
 Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
 Dim v1 As String, v2 As String
 Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
 K = 1
 N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 v1 = s1.Cells(2, 1).Value
 v2 = s1.Cells(2, 2).Value

 For i = 3 To N
  vn1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
  vn2 = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
  If vn1 = v1 Then
     v2 = v2 & "," & vn2
  Else
     s2.Cells(K, 1) = v1
     s2.Cells(K, 2) = v2
     v1 = vn1
     v2 = vn2
     K = K + 1
  End If
 Next i

 s2.Cells(K, 1) = v1
 s2.Cells(K, 2) = v2
```

End Sub

Comment: While the concept is there the issue is you are looking backward and not forward. The row is asking "if I am new then copy the previous row " which is asking for trouble as somewhere a row might be missed. The row should rather ask "if there is more like me in front then save myself else copy myself and any saved rows."

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need VBA for this, unless you need to do it regularly with several different data sets. This method concatenates the URLS strings for x number of rows as long as the SKUs match (where x is the max number of URLs per SKU). You also add a Primary SKU column to use as a filter to discard duplicates. Hide the original URL column and copy and paste to a new sheet.

The formula only solution:
[image]

Formula view:
[image]

Comment: a vba would be ideal as got a good few sheets to do

Comment: Let me know if my vba code below works for you @user2962748

Answer (score 0):

Try to code the following algoritm:

```
Urlbuffer = ""
Sku = ""
k = 1
N = *max rows*
s1 = *sheet1*
s2 = *sheet2*

For i = 1 to N
  Sku = s1.cells(i, 1) 
  If Sku = s1.cells(i+1) then
    Urlbuffer =Urlbuffer & " | " & s1.cells(i,2)
  Else
    s2.cells(k, 1) = Sku
    s2.cells(k, 2) = s1.cells(i, 2) & Urlbuffer
    k = k + 1
    Urlbuffer = ""
  End if
 Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365, it is easy to do this with formulas:

***Edit** I see now that there is an `Excel-2010` tag added. I'll leave this answer anyway for others who may have O365*

eg:

- Products: A2:A17
- URL : B2:B17

List of products

```
E2: =SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A17))
```

URLs

```
E3 (and copy down): =TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$17,$A$2:$A$17=E2))
```

[image]

*It is also pretty simple to do this with Power Query.  Just group by the Product; then extract a url pipe-delimited list from the resultant table*